# Writing logging information into file with System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, logging

In my asp.net mvc 3 app I want to track SQL code that is generated by Linq To Sql. I want to write it in a file. Here is what I do:

web.config changes:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
  <listeners>
    <add name="myListener" 
         type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
         initializeData="LogLinqToSql.log" />
    <remove name="Default" />
  </listeners>
</trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

I created a class that should help with writing into file (just found it in one tutorial):

```
public class LogLinqToSql : TextWriter
{
    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        Debug.Write(value);
    }
    public override void Write(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        Debug.Write(new String(buffer, index, count));
    }
    public override System.Text.Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

And the changes in StoreController action method Content that is used to get items from repository and that uses a viewmodel (mabby because of it my code doesn't work):

```
#define TRACE 

public ViewResult Content(string category, int page = 1)
{
    var context = new WebStoreDataContext();

     Trace.WriteLine("StoreController.Content BEGINS");
     context.Log = Console.Out;

     var model = new StoreContentViewModel
            {
                Items = _itemsRepository.GetItems()
                             .Where(i => category == null || (i.Product != null && i.Product.Category == category))
                             .OrderBy(i => i.ItemId)
                             .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                             .Take(PageSize),

                // initializing other properties
            };

        context.Log = new LogLinqToSql();
        context.SubmitChanges();
        Trace.WriteLine("StoreController.Content ENDS");
        Trace.WriteLine("");

        return View(model);         
}
```

Only "BEGIN" and "END" lines appeare in the .log file.

So, am I doing something completely wrong and there is another approach to write logging information into file or I just need to fix some part???

Thanks for help in advance!

**Edits:**

Also tried this in action method:

```
context.Log = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Aleksey\repos\2\WebStore\WebStore\LogLinqToSql.log");
```

But I get an IOException: The process can not get access to this file cause this file is already used by other process.

Here is the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948085/how-do-you-get-linq-to-sql-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to put context.Log into data model class where the actual query is created. Here is the method from ItemsRepository class:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems(string category)
    {
        // writing info into Trace file
        _dataContext.Log = Console.Out;

        var result = _dataContext.Items.Where(
            i => category == null || (i.Product != null && i.Product.Category == category))
                                 .OrderBy(i => i.ItemId);

        _dataContext.Log = new LogLinqToSql();
        _dataContext.SubmitChanges();
        return result;
    }
```